# Can I use the word ''as'' as (relative) pronoun like ''which'' or ''that''?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

in the following context, the words 'such' and 'as' make me confused, and the verb 'is meant' between 'such' and 'as' more make confued.

Should I take as:

''it is meant that such kind of mental concentration which is directed towards morally wholesome object.''?

How should I know simply?
Explain me please...

Thanks to All...

Context:

> The eighth stage is right concentration of mind. Such a kind of mental concentration is meant, as is directed towards a morally wholesome object, and always bound up with right thought, right effort and right mindfulness.

Source:
Page. 4
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka Mahthera

Comment: [correction: explain **this to me**, not explain me] These texts are translations and cannot be used to show how English is used. as is means: like mental concentration direction towards x. And *as* here is not like that or which at all.

Comment: This is bad writing. Not worth learning from it.

Comment: Thanks. Do you say translation texts? Please shere me this imformation...

Comment: @SakyaKim If you want Lambie's attention, use the "@" symbol before their username and they'll get a notification that you've replied to them, like I did with your name in this comment

Comment: I don't feel like this sentence is very well written.  I think the author meant, "The kind of mental concentration that we mean is directed towards a morally wholesome object..." but the original phrasing is not at all clear or fluent.

Comment: Thanks a lot @gotube for your caring...

Comment: @Lambie, Thanks in advanced. Do you mean translation texts? what is original language of this?  German?  Please shere me this imformation...

Comment: I guess he was originally German so I have no idea what language this was originally written in. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyanatiloka It says titles in English. So, these are all translations, he didn't write in English.

Comment: yes, @Lambie. Some native also guess like you, and some say that was abbreviations trancript from Radio lecture, but the fact has been not found until now.

Answer (score 0):

In this context 'as' is synonymous with 'that'.

'is meant' means - 'is intended'

'Such a kind' means 'this type of' or 'this kind of'.

It could be rephrased: The type of mental concentration intended is one that is directed towards...